# "webpack -p --mode production" is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm making react small application with webpack.
Running scripts in package.json but is not working.
Building developing mode success.
Building production mode with no option failed.

Scripts

```
// 
scripts {
  "build-prod": "webpack -p --mode production",
  "build-dev": "webpack -d --mode development"
}
```

Error message is

`npm run build-prod`

> react-scratch@1.0.0 build-prod /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch
>   webpack --mode production
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: "." is not in the SourceMap.
>       at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_sourceContentFor [as sourceContentFor]
>   (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:753:13)
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/applySourceMap.js:88:47
>       at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:230:9)
>       at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:226:13)
>       at applySourceMap (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/applySourceMap.js:58:13)
>       at SourceMapSource.node (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/SourceMapSource.js:36:11)
>       at SourceMapSource.proto.sourceAndMap (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/SourceAndMapMixin.js:29:18)
>       at getTaskForFile (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:64:30)
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:200:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:177:12
>       at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10),
>   :7:1)
>       at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1385:42
>       at eval (eval at create (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10),
>   :11:1)
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:321:9
>       at step (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:87:9)
>       at /Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:111:15
>       at tryCatcher (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
>       at Promise._fulfill (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:643:18)
>       at Promise._resolveCallback (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:437:57)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:529:17)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
>       at Promise._fulfill (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:643:18)
>       at Promise._resolveCallback (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:437:57)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:529:17)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
>       at Promise._fulfill (/Users/ohmihiroki/Dev/my_portfolio/react-scratch/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:643:18)

Project directory

```
├── node_modules
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       └── main.min.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── App.js
│   └──index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
var debug   = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path    = require('path');

/** @type import('webpack').Configuration */
module.exports = {
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  context: path.join(__dirname, "./src"),
  entry: { main: "./index.js" },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: ["babel-loader"]
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/js"),
    filename: "[name].min.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].min.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
    inline: true
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      "@": path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    }
  }
};
```

Please give me advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using these version

```
"webpack": "^4.29.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
```

So the command will be

```
"prod": "webpack -p --mode=production",
"start": "webpack --mode=development",
```